# Sum of all rows to calculate DPMO

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and i need to calculate the DPMO based on a column after i sum all the User

```
   User    Transaction    Pick Defects  
   anter       4229           58     
   billy       2541           52
   john        2549           123
   mary        1254           71
   dan         4874           12
```

I want to return only one row that will calculate DPMO for pick defects.

```
Defect Type   DPMO
Pick Defect   20457

df['DPMO'] = df['Defects']/(df['Transaction'] + df['Defects']) * 1000000
```

The above code gives me per user but i want total DPMO for  pick defect from all user. What should be my approach to solve this

Comment: do you need sum at the end?

Comment: Yes only sum  for all transaction and pick defects and calulate the dpmo from sum. I want dpmo for pick defect as  whole rather than per user which is what my code gives right now

Comment: `s = df[['Defects','Transaction']].sum()`.....`s['Defects']/(s['Transaction'] + s['Defects']) * 1000000`?

Comment: Ok this give me defect and Transaction sum. It is on the right direction.I want to display this as a new dataframe with one column dpmo and pick defect on the row. I am working on it

Comment: use `s = (df[['Defects','Transaction']].sum()..... s['Defects']/(s['Transaction'] + s['Defects']) * 1000000).reset_index(name='DPMO')`